# Добавление новых данных в подгружаемый выпадающий список в случае отсутствия данных

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Существует выпадающий список, данные в который подгружаются из другой страницы Google Таблицы.
Вводя данные в поле выпадающего списка, google sheet подсказывает, выбрать те, которые уже существуют.
Нужно сделать так, если вводятся новые данные, которых не было в списке, то они добавлялись бы в список.

Подробнее показано на скриншоте[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны расширить справочник номенклатуры данными из списков. Или наполнять номенклатуру из списков. К сожалению, понять, что вам подойдет лучше невозможно, потому что скриншот - это не пример, и гадать тут бессмысленно.

Я использую такую конструкцию:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE({
  'Рабочий'!D2:D;
  'Архив I'!D2:D;
  'Архив II'!D2:D;
  I2:I}
);1;1)
```

где `'Рабочий'!D2:D` - текущий лист, `'Архив I'!D2:D` - архивы, `I2:I` - неизменная номенклатура.

В проверке данных уже ссылаюсь на данные, которые возвращает моя формула.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]